# Loading on click on all "a" HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show loader when someone clicks on any  element on my site.

My Code:

```
(function ($) {
    $('body').append("<div id='loader-box'></div>");
    $("loader-box").html("");
    $("a").on('click', function (e) {
        $("loader-box").html("<div class='loader-wrapper'><div class='loader-image'></div></div>");
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The problem is that append does not work. I do not understand why. Thanks!

**--- UPDATE ---**

I found a solution, thanks to all especially Andrei Cristian Prodan who helped me to solve the problem with .on() function. I also use the wrong function to add "loader-box" div.

This is my code:

```
(function($){
    $("body").prepend('<div id="loader-box"></div>');
    $("#loader-box").html("");
    $("html").on("click", "a",function(){
        $("#loader-box").html('<div class="loader-wrapper"><div class="loader-image"></div></div>');
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `$("loader-box")` use `$("#loader-box")`

Comment: ^ you're missing the hash, and this sounds like the most annoying UX ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a "#" in your selector $("#loader-box");

Also if you are executing this code before the anchors exist in your page (for e.g. at the top of your body or inside the header), the click will not be assigned because $('a') will be empty.

Do this instead: `$('html').on('click', 'a', function() {...} );`

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are just a little off; missing #:

```
<script>
$(function($){
    $('body').append("<div id='loader-box'></div>");
        $("#loader-box").html("");
        $("a").on('click', function(e){
            $("#loader-box").html("<div class='loader-wrapper'><div class='loader-image'></div></div>");
        });
});
</script>
```

And DOM ready needs to be written correctly.